# How to pass inline css from a function in one file to a function in head tags in another file

Tags: php

I want to dynamically pass inline CSS to the head tag of a php file and I've been trying to achieve this with 2 functions.

In file **head.php**

```
<?php include 'process.php'; ?>
<head>
<?php cssInline(); ?>
</head>
```

In the file **process.php**. This is just my conceptual logic of what is expected.

```
function cssInline() {
    echo '<style>'.getInlineCss().'</style>';
}

function getInlineCss($css) {
    return $css;
}
```

Putting the process to work in file **foot.php**. It is a conditional call to alter the margin when a specific object is set.

```
<?php 
if( isset($player) )
    getInlineCss('body {margin-bottom: 60px;}'); 
?>
```

Expected result

```
<head>
<style>body {margin-bottom: 60px;}</style>
</head>
```

All those methods along with numerous other attempts have failed to produce. I even tried DOMDocument but there was an issue with page load time.

There is no class in use.

Comment: `echo '<style>'.getInlineCss().'</style>';` - `getInlineCss()` requires a parameter `$css` to return, you call it with no parameter.

Comment: @kerbholz I am aware of that but what would I place as a param to get the value from foot.php? If a variable is used, PHP complains that at least one parameter is expected. I've done that.

Answer (score 1):

I've defined the following method which **successfully process the inline CSS as desired**

```
class DocumentHead
{
    public $cssrules = [];

    public function add($cssrule)
    {
        $this->cssrules[] = htmlentities($cssrule);
    }

    public function getInline()
    {
        $n = "\n";
        return '<style>'.$n.implode($n, $this->cssrules).$n.'</style>';
    }
}
```

Set the class as variable

```
$css = new DocumentHead;
```

Output the CSS entries in the head tags as sent from other files

```
<head>
<?php echo $css->getInline(); ?>
</head>
```

Set CSS inline rules from other files

```
$css->add('.footer {color: #111111;}');
$css->add('body {background: #ffcc00; font-family: verdana;}');
```

Result

```
<head>
<style>
.footer {color: #111111;}
body {background: #ffcc00; font-family: verdana;}
</style>
</head>
```

#### Update:

Just realized that the css rule setter must be declared before the instance of the getter else the output is null and I have not yet determined a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because your call to function:

```
echo '<style>'.getInlineCss().'</style>';
```

Passes an empty argument.

The argument (CSS) passed is not saved anywhere.

You can define a class and save it to a class variable.

You are writing two functions.

But, your desired functionality will work only when they are class methods of same class.

You can go for a single function like:

```
function cssInline($css) {
 return '<style>'. $css .'</style>';
}
```

And call it by:

```
<head>
<?php echo cssInline(); ?>
</head>
```

Again, you should `return` instead of `echo` as in case of `echo`, you do not have any control of function output.

You just call the function, and the output is printed.

Comment: The single function was the first method I tried and it didn't work because PHP throws an error of "too few arguments". There is no class in use now. Are you saying that the process will only work with a class?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a parameter to cssInline.

```
function cssInline($cssString) {
    echo '<style>'.getInlineCss($cssString).'</style>';
}

function getInlineCss($css) {
    return $css;
}
```

Comment: Where is the value for $cssString coming from?